# Recover current value in checkBox during gridView Editing - WebForm C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I have a simple checkBox in Editable gridView :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editable">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# Item.IsEditable %>" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxEditable " runat="server" Text="Editable"></asp:CheckBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I click on edit button in the row, I would like that checkBox is already checked if value is true. (IsEditable is a boolean) 
Text Field is easy because I have a BindItem on Text property in EditItemTemplate. But it's not the same for checkBox or dropdownlist

GridView

[image]

I use a UpdateItem Method to update my data in database. I tried a small condition to check my checkBox but it does'nt work.

```
public void GridViewRisquesAggravants_UpdateItem(IndexViewModel item)
{
 try
   {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
       CheckBox chbEdit = (CheckBox)GridView.Rows[this.GridView.EditIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxEditable") 
          if (item.IsEditable)
              chbEdit.Checked = true;

        new TypeService().Update(new Type
        {   
          IsEditable = item.IsEditable, 
        });
        this.GridView.DataBind();
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      throw;
    }
}
```

It makes sense because I am not in the right function to declare this. But I just have 3 methods in my webform.

```
SelectMethod="GridView_GetData"
UpdateMethod="GridView_UpdateItem"
DeleteMethod="GridView_DeleteItem"
```

Where can I do this?
(And I have the same problem with datas on dropdownList. I don't know where I recover current value during editing)

Thanks in advance
(Sorry I am beginner about webforms and my english is not perfect)

Evy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code instead for checkbox declaration in edit template

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean("true") %>' />
```

Comment: Thank you! This a good Idea. I was looking for a solution like this, directly in webform. But I don't want the default value is true. I want the box to be checked only if "IsEditable = true" in my database.

Comment: you can add a condition in <%# Convert.ToBoolean("true") %>
this acts as C# code and work as row databound event and use EVAL for the datafeild to check

Comment: check the following example

**<asp:Repeater ID="ProductList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> for only <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}") %>
        <br />
        <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID", "details.asp?id={0}") %>'>See Details</a>
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>**

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox chbx = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("CheckBoxEditable") as CheckBox;
  if (chbx != null && chbx.Checked)            
{
  //code here
}
else 
{
  //else condtion
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I take it because it's a better way to write it but it's not a solution about my problem. I would like that my checkBox already checked if boolean value is true.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I do this?

Try it in `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chbEdit = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoxEditable");

        string value = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
        if (value=="True")
            chbEdit.Checked = true;
        else
            chbEdit.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add OnRowDataBound in GrindView `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >`

Comment: Thank you! :) It's also a good idea. Maybe cleaner than condition in aspx file. But I have System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, index was out of bounds. I am going to look for a solution

Answer (score 0):

I added the property `Checked=<%# BindItem.IsEditable %>` on CheckBox Control and it works perfectly.